# Scheme macro for "or"

Tags: scheme

I'm going through Kent Dybvig's "The Scheme Programming Language" in order to learn Scheme macros's.

In section 8.2 
http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/syntax.html#./syntax:h2
he has the example for the "or" macro of

```
(define-syntax or
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_) #f)
     ((_ e) e)
     ((_ e1 e2 e3 ...)
      (let ((t e1)) (if t t (or e2 e3 ...))))))
```

Is there some reason he didn't use the more simple form of:

```
(define-syntax or
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_) #f)
     ((_ e) e)
     ((_ e1 e2 ...)
      (let ((t e1)) (if t t (or e2 ...))))))
```

Do the two forms expand equivalently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, it's done to make things a little clearer -- your simpler form depends on the order of the cases, since `(or x)` can match both of the second and third rules.  So making the cases mutually exclusive makes it easier to read and also more robust.

(BTW, there's a more subtle point there, which I initially thought that you were asking about: why not simplify it even further to:

```
(define-syntax or
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_) #f)
    ((_ e1 e2 ...)
     (let ((t e1)) (if t t (or e2 ...))))))
```

?)

Comment: ... embarrassed at how long it took me to figure that out :).

Comment: @eli I have just seen in Kent Dybvig's book that he has an exercise 3.2.6 stating that your shorter version of the or macro isn't equivalent to his longer version.  The link is: http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/further.html#g61 .  I'm not sure the reason? Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: @HarrySpier: he gives a good hint...  If you want a possibly more direct hint, see how this expands: `(define (loop) (or 'foo (loop)))`

Answer (score 2):

A subpattern followed by `...` can match zero or more elements of the input. Using `e1 e2 e3` makes this case uniquely different than the preceding one.

Comment: Not really, note that Harry's simpler form still evaluates to the correct values.

Comment: Eli, yes, your "making the cases mutually exclusive makes it easier to read and more robust" is what I was trying to say with "makes this case uniquely different than the preceding one."

Comment: @eli Thanks Eli.  In Racket if I type something like     (expand '(or a b c)) it shows me what the "or" macro expands to, but is there a way in Racket to see not what a macro expands to, but the macro form itself of Racket forms that are macros.

Comment: @Harry: try the macro stepper, the standard hiding policy will not show `or` expansions, so you'll want to click the `or` to get it focused, then right-click and choose to show it.